# Is there a way to promote drupal.SE on questions about Drupal on SO?

Tags: discussion, support

I notice that there are Drupal questions that are being asked on SO. I understand that some users prefer to not ask a question on a site that is still in beta, but maybe there are also users who don't know of drupal.SE and would ask questions on drupal.SE, if they would know it exists.

Is there a way to promote drupal.SE to who read SO questions about Drupal?
I have noticed that SO shows questions asking in other SE sites. Does SO shows questions asked on drupal.SE exclusively to users reading Drupal related questions?

Comment: Related: [Appropriate to Plug drupal.stackexchange.com on stackoverflow.com?](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37/appropriate-to-plug-drupal-stackexchange-com-on-stackoverflow-com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, SO will feature popular Drupal questions in house ads -- as it does for all sites in our network.

It is OK, within reason, to leave comments pointing users who commonly ask Drupal questions on SO to this site. But make sure you only do this for users who have a number of Drupal questions in their history, please!

Comment: Are these ads related to the tags currently visible? Will I have a higher chance of seeing a Drupal ad when browsing the Drupal tags?